# Why isn't my documentation showing up in Hackage?

Tags: haskell, documentation, hackage

Documentation for [my recently updated package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma) on Hackage [isn't showing up](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma-0.0.2.12/docs/Crypto-Enigma.html#v:enigmaEncoding), even though it has now been a few days since the update. The previous version had [complete documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma-0.0.2.11/docs/Crypto-Enigma.html#v:enigmaEncoding), and I've made no changes in this update that would have affected package documentation.

Why isn't my documentation showing up in Hackage? Is there an outage or known delay in document building, or can I monitor the status of document building somewhere?

Comment: [Related?](https://blog.hackage.haskell.org/posts/2018-04-26-downtime.html)

Comment: Yes, you can do something to force documents - you can upload your own haddocks to hackage.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Does that address the question?

Comment: Indeed, uploading your own also means you can generate it with proper source hyperlinks.

Comment: You asked lots of questions. I believe my statement addresses one of them but you are the authority on that, not me.

Comment: For a simple way of uploading docs yourself, see https://neilmitchell.blogspot.de/2014/10/fixing-haddock-docs-on-hackage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc builder got stuck and has been restarted (along with better auto-restart logic), and will catch up with the accumulated backlog over the course of a few days.

No action is necessary.